# Mailchimp readTimeout error with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp

I have a Ruby on Rails application with the gem Gibbon in order to integrate my app with Mailchimp.

The code is very straightforward:

```
@@gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'])
@@mailchimp_list = 'ID_LIST'
@@mailchimp_partner = 'ID_LIST_1'
@@mailchimp_affiliate = 'ID_LIST_2'
@@mailchimp_temp = 'ID_LIST_3'
```

Then during the user subscription:

```
@@gibbon.lists(@@mailchimp_list).members.create(body: {email_address: email, status: "subscribed", merge_fields: {FNAME: first_name, LNAME: full_name}})
```

Yesterday the last line of code threw that error:

```
Gibbon::MailChimpError (Net::ReadTimeout @title=nil, @detail=nil, @body=nil, @raw_body=nil, @status_code=nil)
```

The error started to appear randomly and the next day it was gone and everything worked again.

I think it's an error from the Mailchimp side, what can I do in those cases?

Comment: You could put a rescue info in there and schedule a delayed job to rerun at a later time.

Comment: Yes I think I will do something like that! But how can I test this case without witing for the timeout to happen again?

Comment: You could test it by mockin/stubbingg out the call. You can see an [rspec example here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class)